# Json deserialization with array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a problem with json deserialization

JSON string

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "marketId": "1",
  "userId": "2",
  "svisorId": "1",
  "orders": "[{\"Id\": 3, \"Count\": 1, \"Price\": 1000, \"Weight\": 1500, \"ShareId\": 0}]",
  "date": "1516770391",
  "totalWeight": "1500",
  "totalPrice": "1000",
  "debt": "1000",
  "shipped": "0"
}
```

"orders" property is an array of class ProductOrderInfo

Classes

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public int Id
    { get; set; }
    public int MarketId
    { get; set; }
    public int UserId
    { get; set; }
    public int SVisorId
    { get; set; }
    //public List<ProductOrderInfo> Orders; even tried List type
    public ProductOrderInfo[] Orders
    { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice
    { get; set; }
    public int TotalWeight
    { get; set; }
    public int Dept
    { get; set; }
    public bool Shipped
    { get; set; }
    public int Date
    { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOrderInfo
    {
        public int Id
        { get; set; }
        public int Count
        { get; set; }
        public int Price
        { get; set; }
        public int Weight
        { get; set; }
        public int ShareId
        { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserialization with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_string) always fails and throws an exception

```
JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[{"Id": 3, "Count": 1, "Price": 1000, "Weight": 1500, "ShareId": 0}]" to type 'Project.Classes.ProductOrderInfo[]'. Path 'orders', line 6, position 92.
```

I've already searched for a similiar problem like this [C# JSON Deserialization Error Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741111/c-sharp-json-deserialization-error-array) but it didn't help me

Comment: Your problem is that `"orders"` in the JSON is a string, not an array. It is doubly-serialized. It would have worked with `"orders" : [{"id":1, ... }],`. It is visibly serialized with a different tool, by the way, with PascalCase vs. camelCase.

Comment: Didn't notice that it's string. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JSON string as below

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "marketId": "1",
  "userId": "2",
  "svisorId": "1",
  "orders": [{"Id": 3, "Count": 1, "Price": 1000, "Weight": 1500, "ShareId":0}]",
  "date": "1516770391",
  "totalWeight": "1500",
  "totalPrice": "1000",
  "debt": "1000",
  "shipped": 0
}
```

Error is due to the 
you consider Array of orders as string and shipped is bool but consider it as a string.

Use below code for desirialization

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderInfo>(json_string)
```

Comment: I've done these string json_string = tkn.ToString().Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]").Replace("\\", "");
                                lst.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderInfo>(json_string)); Also changed Boolean "shipped" to integer and everything is ok now. Thanks

Comment: Also change `"shipped": "0"` to `"shipped": 0`. And you can also upvote on answer :).

Comment: No need to change the json. String values converts to integer very well. Also I can not upvote the answer as I don't have enough rights